# .load() [from second page] function work, but dont load jquery from second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

i've got a problem. I have two pages.In **page1** i have **div#content**. In this content i load text from **page2** with a function **.load()** [no matter the CSS now],**but the jQuery for page2 is not working on content loaded from page2 to page1** (jQuery is linked in every page).Thanks to all for any idea / solution.

*This code is only to understand what I'm talking to. In my page i have a different code, but with the similar structure.*

`Page1`

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

`Page2`

```
<div id="text">
    <h1 class="clickme">CLICKME</h1>
    <p class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

`jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#content').load('texts/page2.html #text');

    /// and this is not working on page1 only in page2 \\\
     $('#clickme').click( function(){
                $('.hide').slideToggle(600);                                                                
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `$('#clickme').click( function(){` is executed once the document page1.html is loaded, and it add a function to the event on each element with the class. So when page2 loads, the function is not added to the button that were not existing at the first place.

You should consider associating the click event once the page2 is loaded, with the callback function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#content').load('texts/page2.html #text', function() {
    $('#clickme').click( function(){
        $('.hide').slideToggle(600);                                                                
    }); 
  });
});
```

Here is the documentation about load and callbacks : http://api.jquery.com/load/